# Is there a way to search the application log (SLG1) for a particular message?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

Is there a function module (or any other way) that searches the SLG1 application log for a particular message? I.e. the inputs are the message class and ID and maybe a date range.

Comment: It's documented in the official SAP library, I guess you will find by yourself, right? Application Log (BC-SRV-BAL) > Guidelines for Developers > Function Module Overview > Find messages in memory (which means that you first load the log into memory and then you search).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, search for **BAL_*** functions. In general you might need this sequence of functions:

- search on DB for these logs

  ```
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_DB_SEARCH'
    EXPORTING
      i_s_log_filter = g_s_log_filter    "here are the selection filters
    IMPORTING
      e_t_log_header = g_t_log_header
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS         = 0.
  ```
- load logs from DB

  ```
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_DB_LOAD'
    EXPORTING
      i_t_log_header = g_t_log_header
    IMPORTING
      e_t_log_handle = g_t_log_handle
      e_t_msg_handle = g_t_msg_handle
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS         = 0.
  ```
- display logs: get variant which creates hierarchy according to field DETLEVEL

  ```
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_DSP_PROFILE_DETLEVEL_GET'
    IMPORTING
      e_s_display_profile = g_s_display_profile
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS              = 1.
  ```
- create a display profile
- use grid for display if wanted

  ```
  g_s_display_profile-use_grid = p_grid.
  ```
- define up to which level the tree should be expanded

  ```
  g_s_display_profile-exp_level = 1.
  ```
- set title of dynpro

  ```
  g_s_display_profile-title     = TEXT-004.
  g_s_display_profile-head_text = g_s_display_profile-title.
  ```
- set report to allow saving of variants

  ```
  g_s_display_profile-disvariant-report = sy-repid.
  ```
- when you use also other ALV lists in your report,please specify a handle to distinguish between the display variants of these different lists, e.g:

  ```
  g_s_display_profile-disvariant-handle = 'LOG'.
  ```
- call display function module: We do not specify any filter (like S_LOG_FILTER, ...,T_MSG_HANDLE) since we want to display all logs available

  ```
  CALL FUNCTION 'BAL_DSP_LOG_DISPLAY'
    EXPORTING
      i_s_display_profile = g_s_display_profile
      i_t_log_handle      = g_t_log_handle
      i_t_msg_handle      = g_t_msg_handle
    EXCEPTIONS
      OTHERS              = 1.
  ```

Comment: Btw: If anyone wonders if it might be simpler to just access the database tables with the SE16* transactions: Unfortunately the database table that contains the actual messages (BALDAT) is a table cluster. So you are going to need an ABAP program to make sense of the data anyway.

Comment: Table clusters are obsolete since ABAP 7.53. They don't exist anymore in S/4HANA. Unless you use old software like SAP ECC, the messages should be accessible directly at table level too. Logging in ABAP Cloud is of course different (no SLG1 anyway).